# How can I resize the width of a java.awt.Choice control after adding strings

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

Here is my code. Repaint doesn't do anything here. Any ideas?  Because there are no items in the dropdown after init the dropdown is narrow.  After adding the text items the width stays the same.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.*;

//user is prompted to enter a semi-colon delimitted text string

public class ChoiceWidth extends Applet implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

    private Choice m_Choice = null;
    private Button m_Button = null;
    private TextField m_Textbox = null;     

    public void init() {
        m_Button = new Button("Add Items");
        m_Button.addActionListener(this);
        add(m_Button);

        m_Choice = new Choice();
        m_Choice.addItemListener(this);
        add(m_Choice);

        m_Textbox = new TextField(40);
        add(m_Textbox);
    }

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
   {
       String clr=m_Choice.getSelectedItem();
       System.out.println("Selected: " + clr);
   }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        AddItems();
    }

    private void CreateList(String items) {
    String devlist[] = items.split(";");
        for(int i = 0; i < devlist.length; ++i) {
        m_Choice.add(devlist[i]);
        }
        m_Choice.repaint();  //I thought this would resize width - but doesn't
    }

    private boolean AddItems() {
        String devs = m_Textbox.getText();
        if(!devs.isEmpty()) {
        CreateList(devs);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and html

```
<html>
<body>
  Enter a semi-colon delimited text string
  <applet code = "ChoiceWidth.class" width="300" height = "60">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best of your choice is to migrate to the Swing version of your code.

Comment: 1) Use Swing (most GUI developers have never used AWT - the rest of us forget how it works).  2) Why an applet? 3) That HTML is malformed. 4) I suspect the answer is mostly to be found in layouts.